# Using embedded Icon for Tray in c#

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

i embedded a .ico-File in my Project resources.

Now i want to use this icon as the Tray-Icon of the application.

I used

```
notico.Icon = new Icon("tanss.ico");
```

so far, but that depends on the icon file stored in the path of the executable.

How do i access my tanss.ico out of the embedded ressource?

I tried

```
new Icon(Properties.Resources.iconname);
```

without success.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create a new Icon from an Icon. Just use the Properties.Resources.iconname as the Icon instance.

```
notico.Icon = Properties.Resources.iconname;
```

Comment: @Sili: Don't forget to accept my answer if it worked ;) Just click on the white checkmark on the left.